# Postgres: Update OR Delete exactly one row matching WHERE clause where many rows match

Tags: postgresql

I have seen several solutions to this involving selecting with limit 1 and then updating using the primary key. This is the way I'm doing this now, but it is not efficient enough for my application.

Current query:
`UPDATE "MappingTable" SET "DeviceId" = device_id WHERE "MappingId" = (SELECT "MappingId" FROM "MappingTable" WHERE "DeviceId" is null limit 1) AND "DeviceId" IS NULL RETURNING "Code"`

Perhaps it is better to state the problem I am attempting to solve, because I am free to redesign the schema in order to solve the problem. The use case is: We have millions of devices that need to receive a one-time-use code from a table of possible codes. When we return a code, we set a column indicating which device is assigned that particular code. This needs to be as efficient as possible.

What we are doing at present is to have a mapping table with an int primary key, "MappingId", a "Code" column, and a "DeviceId" column. I am Currently testing with one million codes and 10 dummy "clients" banging on the service to test performance. I'm seeing very high amounts of locking and poor performance with a load of several hundred requests/sec, which is lower than what we expect in production.

I can design the database in any manner that will meet the requirement most efficiently. Again, I need to store a list of codes, then update/return exactly one code while recording the device that was assigned that code. I would appreciate any advice on design/query to meet that goal. I'm new to Postgres, so even having read dozens of questions/answers on SO and consulting docs for over a week, I am at a loss.

Comment: If there are CKs (device ID, one time code), what is the need to “limit 1”? Showing a query and actual table definition would add clarity.

Comment: There will be many codes in the table that have not been assigned. I only want to return/update exactly one of them.

Comment: Ah. So this is a “find (and claim) the next free one time code (already existing in a shared table)” task? (Would it not be possible just to find a random ID, then check that, in a large enough space, or must it be an existing generated set?)

Comment: Why do you have a "list of available codes", is it not possible to generate an arbitrary one on-the-fly? Do the codes need to be unique, i.e. can a code be assigned to only a single device (at the same time)? Can one device get multiple codes at once?

Comment: How exactly do you need to assign/unassign a code to a device? Do you assign them in bulk, then unassign them individually when each device "uses" its code?

Comment: @user2864740 - Yes. Exactly.

Comment: @Bergi - I cannot generate the codes. They come from a different system over which we have no control.

Comment: @Bergi - The codes can be used by exactly one device, but that mapping must be permanent. Once the code is claimed, it can never be assigned again.

Comment: I suspect you want to [use `SKIP LOCKED` in your selection query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/188406)

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks for that. I will investigate.

Comment: @Bergi - "SKIP LOCKED" appears to resolve the problem in my local tests. I will have to wait for the team to get in after the weekend in order to fully test it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining which row to update/delete if your query returns many results? Can the solution be as simple as updating the row with `where code = desired_code`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. I have to select exactly one code from an arbitrary list. The querying code has no clue what the codes are. The codes are given to us in bulk by a different vendor.

Comment: How do you even know which code to select then? You can't query for a specific row if your query does not know which one it is.

Comment: I do not know (or care) which code is selected. I just want exactly one available code to be mapped to the device and returned. Make sense?

Comment: So maybe you can write a query to find the first available code using LIMIT n, where n is the number of devices that need to be updated, and then you can update that field for all the devices with a list of codes.